# Convert times with missing time zone

Tags: linq-to-xml

I have an xml file from a 3rd party that does not include time zone info for dates. For example:

```
<RaceDate>2014-01-15+00:00</RaceDate>
```

When I load this like:

```
XElement root = XElement.Load(file);
IEnumerable<DateTime> x = from el in root.Elements("RaceDate") select (DateTime)el;
Console.WriteLine(x.ElementAt(0).ToString());
```

It prints `1/14/2014 7:00:00 PM` The provider is just assuming EST. Is there a way to correct this in LINQ?

I know I can

```
Console.WriteLine(x.ElementAt(0).AddHours(5).ToString());
```

But there are a lot of dates and I'd like to fix it in LINQ. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this:

```
select DateTime.Parse(el).ToUniversalTime()
```

Comment: Thanks. Had to re-work slightly to get to work: `select DateTime.Parse((string)el).ToUniversalTime();`

Comment: Cool. It's probably called ToUniversalTime, I forgot the exact syntax.